# Javascript variable declaration with tags and ID

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to declare a variable to select a button from a btn-group. I have 2 button groups and I'm having trouble separating them from one another in my code. The below code works for a single button group, but, I have two separate button groups on the same page and this code will only let me select one button between both btn-groups. I would like to be able to select one button per btn-group (only one btn-group is shown, the other is similar but with a different name/id).

Is there a way for me to be able to select based on btn-group id?

HTML:

```
<div name="severitButtons" id="severitButtons" class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <!-- start buttons -->
    <!-- Very Negative -->
    <label id="very-low" btn-radio="option.value.toString()" 
      uncheckable="" class="btn btn-default ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        Very low
        <div class="accent-border accent-border-very-low"></div>
    </label>
    <!-- Negative -->
    <label id="low" btn-radio="option.value.toString()" 
      uncheckable="" class="btn btn-default ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng valid-parse">
        Low
        <div class="accent-border accent-border-low"></div>
    </label>
    <!-- Neutral -->
    <label id="moderate" btn-radio="option.value.toString()" uncheckable="" class="btn btn-default ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        Medium<div class="accent-border accent-border-medium"></div>
    </label>
    <!-- Positive -->
    <label id="high" btn-radio="option.value.toString()" 
       uncheckable="" class="btn btn-default ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        High<div class="accent-border accent-border-high"></div>
    </label>
    <!-- Very Positive -->
    <label id="very-high" btn-radio="option.value.toString()" 
      uncheckable="" class="btn btn-default ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
        Very high<div class="accent-border accent-border-very-high"></div>
    </label>
    <!-- end buttons -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    var selector = '.btn-group label';

    $(selector).on('click', function(){
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Second use of `$(selector)` will work, but will add a large overhead. For **each** item it find as part of the `click` event, it will then go off and remove the class for ALL items. (If you found 10 items, the removeClass would effective happen 100 times).  It would be better as another `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IDs of the two button groups are different, you can use the id in the selector to differentiate.

```
<script>
    var selector = '#severitButtons label, #severitButtons2 label';

    $(selector).on('click', function(){
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I had to make two selector variables and separate the functions, but, this worked. Thank you.